# What are this white on black numbers on xamarin's / C# visual windows builds?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I build a Xamarin Project for windows 8.1 or 10 (running it in "local machine") I get some numbers in the top left like this "0":

[image]

I searched about it without luck (probably I am using the wrong keywords), What are those? Can I changed their position or disable them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the windows frame rate counter. If you want to disable it, go to your `App.xaml.cs` file and remove/comment out the following code from the `OnLaunched` method:

```
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! One question. Is this something exclusive from xamarin?

Comment: No, nothing exclusive to Xamarin, that's something you'll find in all universal windows apps - 8.x, Windows phone and UWP afaik

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same question and ended up with that solution. (if someone don't want it to disable permanently.)

```
#if DEBUG
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Activate FPS Counter?");
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", null));
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", null));
            dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
            dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
            var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

            if (result.Label == "Yes")
            {
                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
                }
            }
#endif
```

Don't forget to upvote Frauke`s answer and distante's question.